# HttpContext.Response.RedirectLocation doenst work in chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, response.redirect

I have a multilanguage site. Available languages are English and Dutch. I would like to be able to switch between those languages. So when a visitor clicks on the `NL` language it will point to  `www.website.com/languagecontroller/switchlanguage/language=nl?currenturl=http%3a%2f%2fwww.website.com%2f` (currenturl parameter will be url encoded).

The redirect to the page and correct language will be done via the code below:

```
HttpContext.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 302;
HttpContext.Response.RedirectLocation = currentUrl;
HttpContext.Response.End();
```

The result (only in Chrome) I get is a blank page with in the address bar: `www.website.com/languagecontroller/switchlanguage/language=nl?currenturl=www.website.com`

The coding seems fine because Internet Explorer and Firefox are working fine, only Chrome is having issues. I've also tried `Server.Transfer()` but I experienced the same issue there.

I've been searching for the issue and it looks like it has to do with Chrome caching. But I'm not sure and was not able to find the/a solution. I don't see what might be wrong or how I can fix this so Chrome doesn't give me issues.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

RFC 2616 requires an absolute URL in the HTTP LOCATION header, your URL is not well formed (from what I see above), add (http://) and convert it to well-formed absolute URL. Check, perhaps that would solve the problem.

The issue seems to be in the URL.

Hope this helps.

thanks

Comment: Hi Ironluca, i've updated the URL to the url encode url. In my code it was already like this. Now it also is in my question. Thanks